# Jenkins don't launch "post build" actions when trigger by the timer

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I don't know why post build actions are not launched by jenkins when the build is triggered by the internal timer (typically a nighltly build or a SCM poll)
For the context, our SONAR analysis is configured as a maven post build action but if the job is not launched directly by the user from jenkins web application, sonar is not updated and there is no trace of sonar analysis in the console log. If the job is launched manually all is working well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior can be configured globally or on each Jenkins job in the Sonar configuration section. Here are the available options :

- Skip if triggered by SCM Changes
- Skip if triggered by the build of a dependency
- Skip if environment variable is defined and set to true